# Use same Azure Active directory authentication two access multiple apps

Tags: wordpress, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

Currently I have one mobile app, it's using Azure AD for authenticating users while opening itself. Now I have developed one WordPress site and it's also using Azure AD for authenticating users. Now I have to join my WordPress site to my mobile app(as one page in that app showing some blogs). My question is while clicking this WordPress app page in mobile app it's should not ask for login again to authenticate. Instead of it, it has to authenticate using same Azure AD authentication which mobile application is using. Is it possible ? if yes, how to do ? any example code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both apps are

- In the same Azure AD
- Opened in the same browser
- Users have logged on to either app
- [Consented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/application-dev-consent-framework) to the app (either admin or user)

then single sign-on should take care of signing in your users and they shouldn't see any login page.

Comment: In the case of mobile apps this depends if the webview used for auth in the app and the browser used to access the site share the same cookie jar. Otherwise, no way it's gonna happen. Also hi Kim :)

Comment: Good point, thanks! Long time no see, old friend ;) Offtopic: wanna have lunch some day if you are at the office? But let's have that discussion on a more suitable media ;)